# Procedure or function has too many arguments specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

There are so many questions on SO on this exception. But none of them are useful to me.

Here is my Stored Procedure  :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE HolidayStandardMappingInsert 
    @HolidayID bigint,
    @StandatdID smallint
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO HolidayStandardMapping VALUES(@HolidayID,@StandatdID)
END
GO
```

And here is my Code:

```
int StdId = 0;
                SqlCommand cmdS = new SqlCommand("HolidayStandardMappingInsert", conn);
                cmdS.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


                for (int i = 0; i < cblStandard.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (cblStandard.Items[i].Selected == true)
                    {
                        if (StdId == 0)
                            StdId = Convert.ToInt32(cblStandard.Items[i].Value);
                        else
                            StdId = Convert.ToInt32(cblStandard.Items[i].Value);
                        cmdS.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HolidayID", NewRecordID);
                        cmdS.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StandatdID", StdId);
                        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                        {
                            conn.Close();
                        }
                        conn.Open();
                        int res = cmdS.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        if (res > 0)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }
```

Tell me what is missing?

Comment: You are readding parameters each time you enter a `for` loop. You need to either remove then each time, or create `SqlCommand` inside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using same `SqlCommnad object` for multiple insertions so `previously` added `parameters` are also present.

So either create a new `SqlCommnad object` inside loop or `clear` prevoius parameters.

This is how you can `Clear` Previously added parameters.

```
cmdS.Parameters.Clear();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are adding parameters in a loop.
So after second iteration, your command has 4 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Each time You are adding cmdS.Parameters.AddWithValue in a loop. So after the first iteration, it has already 2 parameters.

You need to clear the command parameters by cmdS.Parameters.Clear() before entering the loop.